# Server's image quality in android

Tags: android, imageview

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shop_image"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shopprofile" />
```

my app connect to server and get image shop profile but images quality lose!
in server save image in size 140px*140px
what's problem?

thanks for help

Comment: Please provide the server response image url..

Comment: Picasso.with(_context).load("http://test.com/Attachment/Shop/Images/" + _shops.get(i).Image + ".jpg").into(holder.image);

Answer (score 0):

One more thing..your image on server has size 140 px x 140 px..and you define it you Image View 140dp x 140 dp..its too high..so image will be stretch ..so please change dp to px..

Comment: but is too small when convert to px

Answer (score 0):

You are sending compressed image to server that's why it's image losing image quality.
Please check first image sending code